# Why do I get "Permission Denied" when trying to get onto mysql using command line?

Tags: mysql, command-line

When i go in C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/bin in my command prompt and enter the command >mysql -u root -p, it says

```
 $ >mysql -u root -p
bash: mysql: Permission denied
```

But when I use the MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client, it just asks my for my password and I'm able to use some commands in there. Why can I use my regular command line? I used windows CMD and git bash and both give me this error. I've already set up a password, but it somehow doesn't let me run that one command.

Comment: Try once using server root user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are typing the `>` in front of `mysql` and you are in the folder `C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/bin` then you will get this error because you won't have permission to create a file called `mysql`. The `>` character is used to re-direct standard output into a file. If you don't put an absolute or relative path in, then it assumes the current folder. You are effectively trying to create a file called `mysql` in that folder. Try typing `./mysql -u root -p` instead.